# how can we use Buildconfig That is automatically generated?

Tags: java, android, debugging, manifest

Builds Config is automatically generated . But when i call This in another method it throws some error .

I also import This Build Config into my java class but  it shows unused import statement . should i need to add something in Android Manifest ?

Comment: sorry i couldn't upload this Picture into my question because of less reputation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide any relevant information to your questions; such as the code, what you've tried and what the error is.

Comment: storedPassword = settings.getString(BuildConfig.PASSWORD_PREFERENCE_KEY, "");
      storedPassword = decryptPassword(storedPassword);
      password = BuildConfig.PASSWORD_SALT + password +  BuildConfig.PASSWORD_SALT;

error is cannot find symbol variable  PASSWORD_SALT,PASSWORD_PREFERENCE_KEY.

Comment: I am trying to make keypad Screen Lock. this code is somewhere i got . but the only problem is there is not AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/PasscodeLock-Android 
This is the link where i got project

Comment: @arbitstudios did your issue got resolved, as I am also facing the same problem. Could you help me for the same?

Comment: the problem didn't solved so i closed my project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100%, but you can try changing your sourcesets block to look like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs += ['src']
        resources.srcDirs += ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs += ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs += ['src']
        res.srcDirs += ['res']
        assets.srcDirs += ['assets']
    }
}
```

You might be accidentally preventing the generated BuildConfig from being included in the classpath, or indeed being compiled into the app.